# Enabling Night Light permanently on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, night-light

I always have had problem with setting Night Light's active range on Ubuntu 20.04.
The most obvious: 0h - 0h does not work.
However setting 8h - 8h at 8.00 o'clock did work until today.
Today it does not enable it and neither I can make it active with any kind of combination of time windows. I cannot see the graphical interface an option at all from now on, therefore I'm interested in:

If there is any command line alternative which can enable the Night Light permanently?

Comment: @UnKNOWn The time from 00:00 to 00:00 in the Night Light settings works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any *simple* command line alternative, but you can keep Night Light on throughout the (24 hours) day using the [**Night Light Slider**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1276/night-light-slider/) GNOME Shell extension. Its main purpose is to add a slider to the system menu to control Night Light's colour temperature:
[image: Night Light Slider here]

But it also provides an option to enable Night Light all the time ('*Enable always*'):
[image: Night Light Slider settings]

This option actually periodically changes Night Light's schedule under the hood in order to  keep it activated all the time.

*P.S.* Refer to this Q&A to learn about installing and managing GNOME Shell extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)

Comment: Many thanks, just one question about Night Light Slider's scope: has effect for browser(s) only or for the entire operating system?

Comment: I don't understand your question completely. In case you're referring to the process of installing a GNOME Shell extension using a web-browser, it's just one way to install (and manage / remove) the extension using the browser as a medium or store. If you choose the option, the extension would keep Night Light, as you know it, enabled throughout the day, there's nothing specific to the browser. But note that it's only for the current user's session, other user's session won't be affected.

Comment: That's answers my question. Thank you pomsky.

Answer (score -2):

Enabling the *Manual Schedule* option worked for me:

[image: Night Light]